# How to properly rotate a custom shape in p5 JS and move it around the canvas without changing its angle?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I have been trying to rotate a custom shape I created with curve vertex using translate() and rotate(). I successfully rotated the shape, but when I change the position of the shape, its angle changes as well i.e. I cannot get the whole shape to move intact across the screen.

My code for the function shape is:

```
function custom_shape() {
  fill(180, 180, 180);
  beginShape();
  curveVertex(cShape_x - 12, cShape_y - 37); 
  curveVertex(cShape_x - 16, cShape_y - 48); 
  curveVertex(cShape_x - 19, cShape_y - 43); 
  curveVertex(cShape_x - 16, cShape_y - 29);
  endShape(CLOSE);
  }
```

I have set up angleMode(DEGREES) in the setup function. To rotate the shape I used:

```
push();
translate((cShape_x - 310), (cShape_y + 18));
rotate(-90);
custom_shape();
pop();
```

My problem arises when I want to change the cShape_x and cShape_y values. The shape in such cases changes its angle and relative position to the other shapes (which translate correctly when changing the cShape_x and cShape_y values).

I could not find appropriate online resources. I found this to be the best explanation, but it is still not clicking for me. https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The cShape_x and cShape_y are variable points (found outside of the shape) that will need to change several times further down the project.

Comment: But there is no need to use the coordinates in `custom_shape`, isn't it? Do something like `beginShape();` `curveVertex(-12,  37); ...`. And use `cShape_x` and `cShape_y` in `translate` only.

Comment: @Rabbid76 You are great! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, @Rabbid76. It's solved :) Just check-marked your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add the coordinates to each individual point in `custom_shape()`.

```js
function custom_shape() {
    fill(180, 180, 180);
    beginShape();
    curveVertex(-12, -37); 
    curveVertex(-16, -48); 
    curveVertex(-19, -43); 
    curveVertex(-16, -29);
    endShape(CLOSE);
}
```

It is sufficient to  use `cShape_x` and `cShape_y`  in `translate` only:

```js
push();
translate((cShape_x - 310), (cShape_y + 18));
rotate(-90);
custom_shape();
pop();
```